# Python Pandas DF Create New Variable based on List of Columns

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have a df with some binary columns (1,-1) and a list with N columnnames.
i need to create a new variable like that ...

> df['test'] = np.where(((df['Col1']==-1) & (df['Col2']==-1)), -1, 0)

... but dynamically. so the rule is: if all the columns from the list have the same value (1,-1) take it. otherwise value = 0. the length of the list is not fixed. can i simply iterate over the list and create that "where-String" or is there a more elegant way?

thanks!
e

Answer (score 1, accepted):

IIUC you can just do

```
df['test'] = np.where((df[list_of_col_names] == -1).all(axis=1), -1, 0)
```

So here you can just pass a list of cols of interest to sub-select from the orig df as all you're doing is comparing all cols of interest to a scalar value, you then do `all(axis=1)` to test if all row values match that value and pass the boolean mask to `np.where` as before.

e.g.:

```
list_of_col_names = ['col1','col2']
df['test'] = np.where((df[list_of_col_names] == -1).all(axis=1), -1, 0)
```

it's important you pass an actual list of names or iterable, if you do this it'll raise a `KeyError`:

```
df['test'] = np.where((df['col1','col2'] == -1).all(axis=1), -1, 0)
```

as it'll interpret this as a tuple and it's likely that this column `'col1','col2'` doesn't exist

Comment: great thanks. but i think you have some brackets too much: df['test'] = np.where((df[list_of_col_names] == -1).all(axis=1), -1, 0)

Comment: @Ele that's just to emphasise that you should pass a list rather than a string of names: `df[['col1','col2']]` instead of `df['col1','col2']`, in the past I've had people comment that  it didn't due to the latter, I'll edit and make it clearer